# The data in my database does not show up in my data grid view

Tags: c#, sqlite

It does save in my database and it shows in data grid view but after I close and open it again it does not show my data from database to data grid view

```
public partial class Student : Form
    {
        private SQLiteConnection con;
        private SQLiteCommand cmd;
        private SQLiteDataAdapter DB;
        private DataSet DS = new DataSet();
        private DataTable DT = new DataTable();

        public Student()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadData();
        }
        string sql;
        private void setConnection()
        {
            con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source = library.db;Version = 3;New = false;Compress= true");
        }
        private void ExecuteQuery(string txtQuery)
        {
            setConnection();
            con.Open();
            cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = txtQuery;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

        }
        private void clearme()
        {
            txt_fname.Clear();
            txt_lname.Clear();
            txtAddress.Clear();
            txtContact.Clear();
            txtCourse.Clear();
        }

        private void LoadData()
        {
            setConnection();
            con.Open();
            cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            string CommandText = "Select * From Student where BorrowerId='" + txtBid.Text + "'";
            DB = new SQLiteDataAdapter(CommandText, con);
            DS.Reset();
            DB.Fill(DS);
            DT = DS.Tables[0];
            dtg_ABorrowLists.DataSource = DT;

        }
```

/It does save in my database and it shows in data grid view but after I close and open it again it does not show my data from database to data grid view
private void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string gender;
if (rdio_female.Checked)
{
gender = "Female";
}
else
{
gender = "Male";
}

```
                string txtQuery = "insert into Student (`BorrowerId`, `Firstname`, `Lastname`, `Address`, "
                       + "`Sex`, `ContactNo`, `CourseYear`)"
                       + "values ('" + txtBid.Text + "','" + txt_fname.Text + "','" + txt_lname.Text
                       + "','" + txtAddress.Text
                       + "','" + gender + "','" + txtContact.Text + "','" + txtCourse.Text
                       + "')";
                ExecuteQuery(txtQuery);
                LoadData();
            
            
        }

        private void txtBid_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            sql = "SELECT * FROM `tblborrower` WHERE `BorrowerId` = '" + txtBid.Text + "'";
            

            if (DT.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                txt_fname.Text = DT.Rows[0].Field<string>("Firstname");
                txt_lname.Text = DT.Rows[0].Field<string>("Lastname");
                txtAddress.Text = DT.Rows[0].Field<string>("Address");
                txtContact.Text = DT.Rows[0].Field<string>("ContactNo");
                txtCourse.Text = DT.Rows[0].Field<string>("CourseYear");
               

                if (DT.Rows[0].Field<string>("Sex") == "Female")
                {
                    rdio_female.Checked = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    rdio_male.Checked = true;
                }
                btn_delete.Enabled = true;

            }
            else
            {
                btn_delete.Enabled = false;
                clearme();
            }

        }

        private void btn_delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this borrower?", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                String txtQuery = "delete from Student where BorrowerId = '" + txtBid.Text + "'";


                MessageBox.Show("Borrower has been deleted in the database.", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                ExecuteQuery(txtQuery);
                LoadData();
            }
        }

        private void btn_New_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.clearme();
        }

        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its because `txtBid.Text` is empty when you initialize student. Therefore, the query isn't returning any data, specifically in `LoadData`. On another note, use parameters to prevent SQLi and dispose objects that implement `IDisposable`.

Comment: how do I do it?